# Как исправить ошибку при миграции БД (PostgreSQL) при деплое проекта Django 1.11.2 на удалённый сервер?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, миграция

Доброго времени суток, сообщество. Возникла проблема с миграциями БД при переносе уже готового проекта Django 1.11.2 на боевой VDS (Debian 8 x64, nginx, PostgreSQL 9.6).

Сама таблица в базе данных пустая, в `settings.py` прописаны параметры для соединения (и протестированы). Структура проекта довольно простая – три приложения: `myproject` (первоначальное, где настройки), `clients` и `citizenship`.

При этом, модель из `citizenship` является полем `ForeignKey` для модели из `clients`. Модель из `clients`, в свою очередь, используется в качестве `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

**citizenship/models.py**

```
class Citizenship(models.Model):
    """ Citizenship model """
    name = models.CharField(_('Country name'), max_length=55, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_available_for_order = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Citizenship'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Citizenship'

    def __str__(self):
        # Display model output like `USA`
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

**clients/models.py**

```
class Client(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ Client model """
    email = models.EmailField(_('E-mail'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First name'), max_length=155, blank=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField(_('Middle name'), max_length=155, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last name'), max_length=155, blank=False)
    gender = models.IntegerField(_('Gender'), choices=GENDER, default=0)
    # add relationship to `Citizenship` model
    citizenship = models.ForeignKey(Citizenship, on_delete=None, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(_('Birthday'), blank=False, null=True)
    visa_start_date = models.DateField(_('Visa start date'), blank=True, null=True)
    visa_end_date = models.DateField(_('Visa end date'), blank=True, null=True)
    # upload passport copy to ./upload/YEAR/MONTH/DAY folder
    passport_copy = models.ImageField(
        _('Passport copy'),
        validators=[validate_image_extension],
        upload_to='docs/%Y/%m/%d/',
        blank=True, null=True
    )
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'citizenship', 'birthday', 'gender', 'passport_copy']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Client'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clients'

    def __str__(self):
        # Display model output like `John Doe (john@doe.com)`
        return '{} {} ({})'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email)
```

Порядок действий такой:

1. Делаю `git clone` репозитория (приватный на GitHub)
2. Создаю виртуальное окружение `python3 -m venv venv`
3. Устанавливаю зависимости `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Далее, запускаю миграции командой `python3 manage.py migrate`, чтобы сделать первоначальную структуру БД, как будто бы это новый проект. Получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "citizenship_citizenship" does not exist
LINE 1: ...enship_citizenship"."is_available_for_order" FROM "citizensh...
                                                             ^
```

Я так понимаю, что эта ошибка говорит о том, что Django не может создать миграции, так как не создана таблица для модели из `citizenship`, на которую ссылается модель из `clients` (как `ForeignKey`). Пробую запустить с параметрами `--fake` и `--fake-initial`. Не работает, вылетает та же ошибка.

Физически удаляю приложение `clients` из папки проекта и чищу все упоминания о нём. И, вуаля, первоначальная миграция для Django прошла успешно! Также, без проблем проходит и `python3 manage.py makemigrations` + последующая миграция в БД для модели `citizenship`. Возвращаю обратно приложение `clients` и делаю ровно те же действия – логично, миграции создаются и мигрируют в БД без ошибок.

Подскажите, как быть? Можно ли как-то скрывать некоторые приложения от первоначальной миграции в пустую БД? Как это делаете вы? Поделитесь, пожалуйста. Ведь каждый раз удалять приложения со связями и вычищать по всему коду их присутствие – достаточно затратно по времени.

Заранее спасибо. Буду рад толковым ответам и комментариям.

Comment: Добавлю, что миграции, которые были сделаны на локалхосте для `clients` и `citizenship` – лежат в соответствующих папках (`migrations`).

Comment: Если база чистая. То достаточно было бы очистить миграции во всех приложениях. И после этого уже создавать таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, спасибо паблику Python programming во Вконтакте.

Дело было вот в чем: каким-то непонятным образом, при применении первоначальной миграции, Django смотрит все файлы всех существующих приложений.

Так вот, в файле `clients/forms.py` у меня было определено поле `select` для связи с моделью Citizenship. При этом атрибут `choices` был равен `Citizenship.objects.all()`.

Иными словами, я вызывал объекты, которых ещё и в по мине не было. Отсюда и ошибка. Как подсказали в публике, этот атрибут можно не указывать — он из модели сам подтянет значения. Убрал, все заработало замечательно, но вопрос "почему так?" остался.

Comment: Ну, все просто. При импорте интерпретируется данная строка и Django надо вытащить все значения, которые могу не существовать.

Answer (score 0):

Надо видеть полный текст ошибки и все миграции. Подозреваю, что порядок миграций неверный. Надо смотреть миграции в clients и убедиться, что первая миграция в clients, которая зависит от citizenship, имеет в зависимостях миграцию citizenship, создающую таблицу citizenship.